# How do I suppress CheckStyle StrictDuplicate warning?

Tags: checkstyle, suppress

I am trying to suppress CheckStyle StrictDuplicateCode warning, and it does not work. 
In my Eclipse project, I have two classes with similar fields:

```
public class MyClass {
    // CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    private String field1;

    private String field2;

    private String field3;

    private String field4;

    private String field5;

    private String field6;

    private String field7;

    private String field8;
}

public class MyDuplicateClass {
    // CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    private String field1;

    private String field2;

    private String field3;

    private String field4;

    private String field5;

    private String field6;

    private String field7;

    private String field8;
}
```

Putting "CHECKSTYLE:OFF" comment in one or both classes does not suppress the warning.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you configured the [SuppressionCommentFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) correctly, for example:

```
<module name="Checker">

  <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
    <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:OFF ([\w\|]+)"/>
    <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:ON ([\w\|]+)"/>
    <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
  </module>

  <module name="TreeWalker">

...
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I am using Checkstyle-5.5. I used exactly the same SuppressionCommentFilter definition. It does not turn off the 'StrictDuplicateCode'